# nodejs Import require conversion

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, npm, require

Learning NodeJs here.  Problem is when I tried to search for answers, I am not finding what I am looking for.  Probably because this is too basic or non-issue.

I am working on nodejs with angular2.  So naturally, I have things like:

```
import { stuff } from 'some_module'
```

But I am trying to work with a package that has usage example of:

```
var stuff = require('some_module')
```

Obviously, my code didn't work when I use import etc. else I wouldn't be posting here.  Is it because I am doing something wrong?  Or am I out of luck such that this particular module doesn't work with import?  Can someone shed some light on how to write proper import statements when I see usage sample of require('some_stuff'), so I can use other modules I download from npm?

thanks in advance.

EDIT:
So I tried npm install requirejs --save.  Then I wrote the require statement above.  But I am getting a 404 on the package...

Comment: You mean you want to use require in node, Right?

Comment: I guess my confusion is whether there is an equivalent to require for import?  Or should I just write "require" in my angular2 components?

Comment: Basically both things do same job for you... What you're using in angular in newer syntax from ES6 and in node you're using older syntax from ES5... (ES5 and ES6 are version name for JS)... My opinion is you should go with newer syntax (You can get it with new version of node i.e. 6.9 or use babel on older version)

Comment: ah good, but my import statement isn't working for me.  I am getting 404 on finding the package.  specifically, this is googleapis package.  I tried getting requirejs and use it like their usage sample but it still didn't work for me.

Comment: so I am doing import {google} from 'googleapis'

Comment: Node doesn't support import/export syntaxes yet.

Comment: @AliGajani do you mean googleapis doesn't support import/export yet?  cause I can certainly import angular2 functionalities without any issues.  Also I have tried to do npm install requirejs and use the require syntax i.e. require('googleapis') but that doesn't seem to work either for some reason.

Comment: I thought you were doing import/export on node. Regardless of any API, node doesn't support them yet. You'll have to use require. If I got your question wrong, forgive me.

Answer (score 10):

You can use **import** but you have to run your app with babel.

you have to add this line to your **package.json** file

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets 'es2015' src/server.js",  
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/.bin/webpack -p"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
```

*src/server.js* file is your main file location

and then run file with following command

`npm run start`

when you use `import { stuff } from 'module';` 
then you can directly use **stuff()** in your program.

but when you use `var stuff = require('module');`
then you need to do **stuff.stuff()** in your program.

Comment: wow interesting, if this is the case, would I then need to go back and refactor/change my code once it is supported?

Comment: yes if you like.  you can take other example from https://github.com/500tech/nodejs-express-es6/

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting that the original syntax

`var stuff = require('some_module')`

is not working for you. If your app was scaffolded from Angular CLI then it should support both imports and require statements out of the box.

for example, I'm using [MSR](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder) in an Angular 2 component like this:

```
var MediaStreamRecorder = require('msr');
```

Comment: it seems when I do require, my lite-server debug is giving me 404 on the package I am pointing to...  I don't recall me having to specify any relative path for require if its in the node_modules folder?  am I wrong?