# Understanding React.js import statment that imports modules from directory

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I am just going through the react-beautiful-dnd ,and came across an example of a board drag and drop, the working of which can be seen [HERE](https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.com/?selectedKind=board&selectedStory=large%20data%20set&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel). When i checked the source code [HERE](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/stories/src/board/board.jsx#L8).

At the beginning of the file the following import statements can be seen:

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled, { injectGlobal } from 'styled-components';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import Column from './column';
import { colors } from '../constants';
import reorder, { reorderQuoteMap } from '../reorder';
import { DragDropContext, Droppable } from '../../../src';
import type {
  DropResult,
  DragStart,
  DraggableLocation,
  DroppableProvided,
} from '../../../src';
import type { QuoteMap } from '../types';
```

I am not quite able to understand the statement `import { DragDropContext, Droppable } from '../../../src';` , what exactly is this statement doing , because i see no `src.js` file from the path this is being imported from , so what exactly is happening at this line of code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript import from '/folder' with index.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442174/javascript-import-from-folder-with-index-js)

Comment: check this may be it help you understand the import key word https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406913/nodejs-import-require-conversion/42407814#42407814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insert a directory to the import path it will default to `index.[supported extensions]`